# Pycharm debugger is connected but doesn't stop at breakpoints

Tags: python, debugging, configuration, pycharm, breakpoints

As you can see, my debugger on pycharm is connected, but the code still run without stop at the breakpoints. What could be the problem please ?

Here is a screenshot after when I play debug mode on the test.py file:

[pycharm debug problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGyYU.jpg)

As you can see, it doesn't stop at the breakpoint. Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Please provide a  [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: My problem is not from a code, but just from my configurations of pycharm i think. When i want to debbug  a simple  code (or any code) with 'Debug', it will connect to debugger  but will not stop at breakpoints. So my question what could be the problem (i think that the problem is in the configurations the pycharm ide). You can see here what it will display :https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGyYU.jpg

Comment: Are you sure that the file you want to debug is "test.py"?

Comment: In my case, that was due to the python script actually started a new process with `os.system(cmd)` and I have to debug that one manually from another configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to fix indent of comparison with `__main__`:

```
def main():
    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```